# Запуск стороннего приложения

Tags: c#

Внутри своего приложения запускаю процесс

```
Process prc = new Process();
prc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
prc.StartInfo.FileName = @"С:\\666\fusioninventory-agent_windows.exe";
prc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/acceptlicense /add-firewall-exception /execmode=Service /installtasks=Full /runnow /no-start-menu /S";
prc.Start();
```

А он мне выдает окно:

> Не удается проверить издателя. Вы действительно хотите запустить эту
>   программу?

Запускаю под админом. Как сделать что бы запуск внутри приложения был автоматическим?

По вопросам что за файл - взято [отсюда](http://www.ekzorchik.ru/2015/06/deployment-agent-on-windows-systems-fusioninventory/) только вместо cmd хочу использовать c#

Comment: А что за файл? Скачан небось из интернета?

Comment: Вначале приложение копирует fusioninventory из сетевого расположения в папку 666 а потом его запускает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раз ваш файл загружен из сетевого расположения, у него может быть проставлен [альтернативный поток данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) `Zone.Identifier`, который означает «файл загружен из интернета, и его не надо запускать».

Судя по всему, для его удаления вам не обойтись без P/Invoke:

```
public static class AlternateStreamUtility
{
    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool DeleteFile(string name);

    const int FACILITY_WIN32 = 7;
    static int HResultFromWin32(int x)
    {
        //#define HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(x) \
        //  ((HRESULT)(x) <= 0 ? ((HRESULT)(x)) \
        //: ((HRESULT) (((x) & 0x0000FFFF) | (FACILITY_WIN32 << 16) | 0x80000000)))
        return (int)((x <= 0) ? x :
          ((x & 0x0000FFFF) | (FACILITY_WIN32 << 16) | 0x80000000));
    }

    const int ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = 0x2;
    static public bool RemoveZoneIdentifier(string fileName)
    {
        if (DeleteFile(fileName + ":Zone.Identifier"))
            return true;
        var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (error == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND && File.Exists(fileName))
            return false;
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(HResultFromWin32(error));
        return false; // not reached
    }
}
```

Код с благодарностью утащен [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6375599/276994) и немного доработан.